# Forcing without choice: when countable sets yield reals

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, forcing, axiom-of-choice

One natural way to show that a forcing adds no new reals is to show that it is countable closed *(EDIT: this is somewhat misleading, see Joel's comment below)*. However, it turns out that this is overkill: there are forcings not adding any reals which are not countably closed, in particular, which *do* add a countable set of ordinals. The simplest example (in the presence of a measurable cardinal) is Prikry forcing, but Namba forcing also works: indeed, Namba (with $\omega_2$ replaced by $\mathfrak{c}^+$) provides a ZFC-provable example.

My question is what happens when we change the base theory to ZF. Is it possible that the reals become more sensitive to changes made elsewhere in the set-theoretic universe? This question arose tangentially in my own research, but honestly I'm interested in it just because it seems a basic question about forcing over ZF-models:

> Is it consistent with ZF that every forcing which adds a countable set of ordinals, also adds a real?

We can also ask a stronger version:

> Is it consistent with ZF that a forcing adds no new reals iff it adds no new countable sets?

but this seems wildly implausible.

---

(For an unrelated but really cool example of how much harder "obvious" facts about forcing become when we move from ZFC to ZF, see [this note](https://archive.uea.ac.uk/~bfe12ncu/sem_2.pdf) by David Aspero giving a proof of a result of Woodin: basically, the statement "every sentence of set theory is forcing-absolute" - which is trivially inconsistent with ZFC - is surprisingly hard to disprove in ZF alone!)

Comment: It's the type of question that is very hard to answer. I would expect one of two possible solutions, which I currently have no time to dig into: (1) Gitik's model, or at least models where the universe is the $\sigma$-closure of singletons, (2) something like Cohen's first model, which has been somehow "saturated" so every forcing which adds a countable set of ordinals will also add reals (here we need to assume no large cardinals exist, otherwise Prikry forcing could provide a counterexample). Of the two, the former has more chance of yielding any actual results. But again, hard questions.

Comment: To my way of thinking, your initial comments about countable closure should instead refer to countable distributivity. The reason is that countable closure is not a forcing invariant---it is not hard to show that every partial order is forcing equivalent to one that is not countably closed. Meanwhile, in ZFC we know that $(\omega,\omega)$-distributivity is equivalent to not adding reals, and $(\omega,\infty)$-distributivity is equivalent to not adding $\omega$-sequences.

Comment: Further complicating the issue with countable closure, note that every countably closed forcing does not add new $\omega$-sequences if and only if DC holds (proved by Gunter Fuchs).

Comment: @Joel: The equivalence between DC and "closure implies distributivity" is a very folklore result, I know that several people have known about it when I came across that same result at some point.

Comment: Let me add to my first comment and say that one of the reasons I feel this is an incredibly difficult question is that we don't know enough "superweird" models of set theory. There are some extensions of ZF which are consistent, modulo large cardinals, that we really know just one way to obtain. And these are the sort of models would be the usual suspects for your question, and many other natural questions. So we have very little to go with, and set theory without choice is incredibly weird. Trust me.

Comment: About that DC result, yes indeed it may have been known earlier, and it isn't difficult. Gunter had put this proof as an offhand remark in a paper of his about ten years ago or more, and I hadn't ever seen it published before that.

Comment: I wonder if we can't just get the desired fact in the Gitik model. After all, every uncountable there has cofinality $\omega$, and so adding a new $\omega$-sequence of ordinals must interleave with an old $\omega$-sequence, and perhaps one can just get a new real that way.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Re: early comments, those are good points; I only mentioned countable closure as context. I've left it as is, since it doesn't affect the questions I'm asking, but I've added a parenthetical remark pointing out the misleading nature of the statement. Re: your most recent comment, I agree the Gitik model is the place to look, and I did a bit, following the idea you mention; unfortunately, I don't see how to guarantee that any of the reals one gets in this way need be new. Thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure if the idea works...